# Download a large Salesforce Report using Python simple_salesforce

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

I am trying to download a large Salesforce Report using Python that has around 300k rows. It seems that because the report is so big the code executes but does not populate the data. Is there a way to increase the size somewhere in the simple-salesforce library?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Instead of _It seems that_, including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.